# How to include mburger.js in mmenu

Tags: javascript, css, hamburger-menu, mmenu

I try to include an animated hamburger in my mmenu.
Documentation here: https://mmenujs.com/mburger/
I downloaded all the Files from gitHub, but I can not find where to include the mburger.js file.
Can somebody help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it in the documentation:

- for css in "Tutorial CSS"
- for js in "Tutorial webcomponent"

Just read it!

Comment: Thanks, but when I only use the CSS File it is not working. So I was wondering if I have to use CSS and JS  or just one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else comes across this, the issue is with the latest couple of versions of mburger. If you use version 2.0.0 you will find the mburger.js file as needed:

https://github.com/FrDH/mburger-webcomponent/releases/tag/v2.0.0